# How to unit test live data running in background thread?

Tags: android, android-livedata

I have a function which emits liveData like this:

```
private fun getArticles(params: Params) {
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        emitter(executeCache(params))
        emitter(Resource.loading(data = null))
        emitter(executeAPI(params))
}
```

}

Since it runs in Dispatchers.IO which is a background thread, my test case is simple like this:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@Test
fun askForCachedDataAndReturnSuccess() {
    throwForceException = false
    testCoroutineRule.runBlockingTest {
        viewModel.getLiveData().observeForever(observer)
        viewModel.start()
        // Pass:
        Assert.assertEquals(viewModel.getLiveData().value?.status, Status.SUCCESS)
    }
}
```

start() internally calls getArticles internally but the issue is the Assert.assertEquals line runs before the liveData emits anything so test case fails.

So how do i write a testcase for a live data running in a background thread?

Comment: Dispatcher should be an interface passed as constructor parameter to the class containing  `getArticles` method, so you can change implementation between normal execution and testing, Read [here](https://medium.com/@PaulinaSadowska/writing-unit-tests-on-asynchronous-events-with-rxjava-and-rxkotlin-1616a27f69aa) and check `BaseSchedulerProvider`, this is for RxJava but you can apply the same concept to Coroutines

Comment: That's what i thought? Any other way ? My architecture is MVVM with Coroutines

Comment: What suggested in the article perfectly fit in the MVVM pattern (I used it a lot) just use the `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. 
This is the best practice, I don't know other ways to do this in a clean way.

Comment: I am using koin to inject my viewmodel so this factory class is not used anymore

Comment: So you are good to go, with a service locator like Koin in place it's a lot easier

Comment: One more thing, as you can see the funtion emits value in CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) thread which is a background thread so my assertion fails because the value is posted later and assertion line call first. Is there a way to syncronously call CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) in a test case ?

Comment: Read here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/